# Convert nested iterables to list

Tags: python, list, generator, iterable

Is there an easy way in python (using itertools, or otherwise) to convert a nested iterable `f` into its corresponding list or tuple? I'd like to save `f` so I can iterate over it multiple times, which means that if some nested elements of `f` are generators, I'll be in trouble.

I'll give an example input/output.

```
>>> g = iter(range(2))
>>> my_input = [1, [2, 3], ((4), 5), [6, g]]
>>> magical_function(my_input)
[1, [2, 3], [[4], 5], [6, [0, 1]]]
```

It would be fine if the output consisted of tuples, too. The issue is that iterating over `g` "consumes" it, so it can't be used again.

Comment: What do you mean by the "corresponding list" of a nested iterable? Do you want to flatten the iterable? If so, do you want a one-level flattening, an n-level flattening, or a recursive flattening?

Comment: I don't want any flattening. By "corresponding list", I mean that I want to preserve the nested structure of ``f``.

Comment: Can you please provide some code sample, what your tried and what you want to get from that ?

Comment: At least, provide an example of the "*before*" and "*after*" of your hoped-for conversion.

Comment: I don't think sample code is needed here.  The question is pretty straight-forward (though I am not sure the answer is)

Comment: @JonWarneke are all of the nester iterables generators?

Comment: @sberry no, the items could be any type of iterable (list, tuple, string, etc.), not just generators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like it would be best to do by checking if each element is iterable, and calling a recursive function over it if it is iterable.  Just as a quick draw-up, I would try something like:

```
import collections

g = iter(range(2))
my_input = [1, [2, 3], ((4), 5), [6, g]]

def unfold(iterable):
    ret = []
    for element in iterable:
        if isinstance(element, collections.Iterable):
            ret.append(unfold(element))
        else:
            ret.append(element)
    return ret

n = unfold(my_input)
print(n)
print(n)
```

which returns

```
$ python3 so.py
[1, [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, [0, 1]]]
[1, [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, [0, 1]]]
```

It's not the prettiest way, and you can find ways to improve it (it puts everything in a list instead of preserving tuples), but here is the general idea I would use.

Comment: Great, this does exactly what I want! I was wondering if there was something similar already implemented in itertools (I always find out about these things long after I would have liked to), but if not, I can always use this code.